# Extract data from Wikitext

Tags: javascript, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata, mediawiki-api

I have some wikitext (edited from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Air)) in a string:

```
{{Short description|Romanian low-cost airline}}{{distinguish|Air Bleu|Airblue|Blue1|Blue Panorama Airlines|JetBlue|Pacific Blue Airlines|Virgin Blue}}
{{Infobox airline
| airline = Blue Air
| logo = Blue-Air logo-01.svg
| logo_size = 200
| IATA = 0B
| ICAO = BLA
| callsign = BLUE AIR
| founded = 2004
| commenced = 2004
| ceased = 
| aoc = 
| hubs = {{nowrap|[[Henri Coandă International Airport]]}}
| focus_cities = 
| bases = <div>
*[[Bacău International Airport]]  
*[[Cluj International Airport]]
*[[Turin Airport]]</div>
| headquarters = [[Bucharest]], [[Romania]]||
| key_people = Steven Greenway, [[CEO]]
| frequent_flyer = My Blue
| lounge = 
| alliance = 
| fleet_size = 15
| destinations = 57
| revenue = {{decrease}} €458 million (2019)
| net_income = {{increase}} €15.1 million (2019)
| website = [https://www.flyblueair.com/ flyblueair.com]
| parent = 
| num_employees = 1,145 (2019)
| image = 
}}

===Destinations===
{{main|List of Blue Air destinations}}
As of February 2021, Blue Air offers flights to 57 scheduled destinations. There are additional seasonal charters operated on behalf of tour operators.

===Codeshare agreements===
Blue Air [[Codeshare agreement|codeshares]] with the following airlines:
*[[Charlie Airlines|Cyprus Airways]]
```

I have to filter some data from the above description, but it's not JSON data. I don't know how to parse Wikitext and extract the data I need:

- List item
- List item
- List item

How can I filter the data?

API is

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=raw&title=Oneworld

Comment: Without knowing the format of the encoded description it's not really possible to reliably parse it. Where are you getting this data from? Can you look up/ask about the descriptions format?

Comment: The `description` is [wikitext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Wikitext) apparently taken from Wikipedia. Wikipedia can convert it to HTML and show it to a human, but it is not really a data format.

Comment: @WanderNauta If i want to use that data in my page using wikipedia API  How can I convert any idea?

Comment: That's not just wikitext; it's malformed wikitext. Did you manually copy-paste sections from the article, or is this really what your API gives you?

Comment: API gave this. I did not copy from website

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=raw&title=Oneworld

Comment: Wikitext source code is a language of itself and also context-dependent so it's a bad idea to try parsing it from the outside. Parsing the result HTML would be a lot easier - just look for the `<li>` tags. Use `?action=render` for HTML of the page content only